# What's an easy way to batch assign (not convert) an ICC profile to .JPG and .CR2 Canon RAW files?

Tags: post-processing, raw, color, color-management, color-spaces

All of the files that comes out of my camera (Canon Rebel T3i) are not assigned a colorspace. Instead, all files the format IMG_XXXX.JPG/CR2 are implied sRGB and _MG_XXXX.JPG/CR2 are implied Adobe RGB 1998 (in the case of the RAW, the embedded preview JPG is stored in the Adobe colorspace).

I'm using Corel AfterShot Pro 1.1 and trying out digiKam on Windows 7 with assigned ICC profiles for the monitors.

Comment: I'm a bit confused...Canon cameras, for quite some time, have had the option to set the ICC tagging of JPEG (not RAW, just JPEG) with a camera setting. You should have the option of selecting whether to tag as sRGB or tag as AdobeRGB. This setting usually has no bearing whatsoever on RAW, which are frequently edited/converted in the ProPhotoRGB space in RAW editors, but it SHOULD be tagging the jpegs....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`exiftool` by Phil Harvey](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for this purpose, check the `-icc_profile` option.